# How to change the lists in python

Tags: python

If you had a list on items e.g `["1", "2"]` but `1` and `2` were unknown how would you remove one from the list so if you removed `"1"` the list would then be `["2"]`?

Comment: Do you want to remove the first element of the list, or do you have a variable set and you  e.g. want to remove all instances of that variable from the list?

Comment: So you want to remove 1 without knowing the position of 1 in the list?

Comment: @AndrewMcClement a variable is set but the variable is unknown and needs removing from the list

Comment: @RichardKYu i know the position in the list i just dont know the variable name or how to remove it

Comment: `del data[0]` or `data.remove("1")` where `data` is your list

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `list.remove` (see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Example:

```py
data = ["1", "2"]
datumToRemove = "1"
data.remove(datumToRemove)
print(data)
```

Note this only removes the first occurrence of `datumToRemove`.

If you wanted to keep the original list, you could use e.g. a list comprehension to generate a new list:

```py
filtered_data = [x for x in data if x != datumToRemove]
```

If you know the position in the list, but not the value, you want `list.pop` (again see above link).

```py
data = ["1", "2"]
data.pop(0)
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

If you don't know the position but you know the name, use `remove()`

```
data.remove("1")
```

If you know the position but not the name, use `pop()`

```
data.pop(index)
```